# how hard is to implement in App Purchase?

Tags: iphone

how hard is to implement in App Purchase?

Is it tricky? or is it probably better to make lite and pro versions of applications?

Comment: @sahil: Thanks for your edit submission. But adding code tags around every proper noun is neither a grammatical edit nor appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a KIT to help other people deal with IAP.

Check it at: http://www.virgiliofavero.com/2009/10/27/vfnstorekit-a-useful-tool-to-manage-in-app-purchase-process/

You will only need to create a provisioning profile with IAP enabled, and create your products on iTunes connect.

Using the kit on my blog, you can manage everything.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a Lite/Pro version is much easier than IAP.  StoreKit requires you to manage a queue of transaction requests; there are a lot of [opportunities for error](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2009/12/25/an-in-app-purchase-brain-dump/).

But IAP comes with advantages of its own: somewhat better piracy protection, and supposedly more people will pay (perhaps for the same reason, but I doubt it).  So, it's more work, but you might get paid for it, so make of that what you will.